# Success function in ajax not returning anything in console

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

Here is my code, and while running it's not giving anything in the console.

This is how I am trying to check the data. If the data correctly I want the mentioned console in success code. But if it is not then I want else code to run. But the if-else conditions are not working properly. I am including PHP code and ajax code which I have tried. Am I doing it right?

```
<?php
    $host = "dpydaldermt01.******.com";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "Test";
    $database_name = "test";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database_name) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error());

    $sql = "select ID, user_email from ci_iwp_wp_users limit 10";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $users = array();
?>
<script>
    (function($) {
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $email =  $row['user_email'];
    ?>
        var mail = "<?php echo $email ?>";
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://bluepages.ibm.com/BpHttpApisv3/wsapi?byInternetAddr='+mail,
            dataType:'someData',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data === '# rc=0, count=0, message=Success') {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });
    <?php
        $users[]=$row;
    }
    ?>
    });
</script>
<?php
    echo json_encode($users);
?>
```

Comment: Please read the AJAX concept. you will get to know lot of things https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Add error block in ajax so it will print error if any. error:function(err){console.log(JSON.stringify(err));} . It may be data encoding error or datatype error just add error block to know. Datatype should be JSOn,XML,Text remove somedata from datatype and add it agianst data:'data'

Comment: Try doing `console.log(data);` before the if statement, you will then see the data returned and will probably find that your if statement isn't correct. Also http://bluepages.ibm.com/ does not resolve so if that is actually the URL you are POSTing to it will fail and the success callback will not be fired.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Remove dataType:'someData', from your code because it always request and response in json so you dont have to declare separately.**